# Deserialize ByteBuffer to InputStream java

Tags: java, arrays, file, inputstream, bytebuffer

I am trying to deserialize ByteBuffer to an InputStream and then to an Object in Java. This is my usecase:

```
# Initially I have a list of objects List<objA> objs, I converted them to a File and then to ByteBuffer like this.

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath)), "UTF-8"));

for (objA obj: objs) {
StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
row.append(obj.getProp1()).append(SEPARATOR);
row.append(obj.getProp2()).append(SEPARATOR);
writer.write(row.toString());
}
File file = new File(filepath);

InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
```

Now, I want to exactly reverse this operation and get the List back, how can I do that? I couldn't find many references on this topic. Can someone help here.

Please note that I cannot change the above code snippet, I want to know how can I get the original list back from the ByteBuffer created from the above code snippet.

Comment: *Now, I want to exactly reverse this operation and get the List back*. Then you should be serializing with `ÒbjectOutputStream`. You're treating it as text, which is not going to enable you to get the object back.

Comment: You have no way of disambiguating your rows, i.e you need another separator. To reverse this process. You have to read the input stream until you find the separator, then convert that value into the corresponding property of `objA`, after you've read all properties of an object, add it to a list -> repeat the process until the inputstream is empty. **Side note**: you also need to use `GZIPInputStream` because you're using `GZIPOutputStream`

Comment: @g00se `ObjectOutputStream` is only used for java serialization. But there are lots of other ways (i.e. serialize to xml, json, csv, etc.). The one OP showed is as valid as your suggestion.

Comment: What actual problem are you having doing this?

Comment: *The one OP showed is as valid as your suggestion*. @Lino : be our guest, please provide a solution for getting back a `List`with the correct elements in it in that case.